# Proguard slowing down android build process too much

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

My Android app build process takes 3+ minutes with ProGuard enabled.  What are some basic things I can do to speed this up?

Comment: Why do you use ProGuard for anything but release builds?

Comment: We could Google this for you but that is not what Stack Overflow if for.  There are plenty of answers if you just look.

Comment: @ianhanniballake It is because there had been issues with ProGuard going through certain libraries and removing too much, causing features to break in the app.  So we wanted to provide consistency in the build process.

Comment: **"What are some basic things I can do to speed this up?"** : Don't use Proguard for every Build, disable auto-building on each code file save, get up and go make a cup of coffee during a build and have a chat with some people (it's funny how time passes more quickly when you're not staring at a screen waiting for something to build).

Comment: Proguard takes 3+ minutes to build my release APK, so I find this question quite valid, because I'd really like to use proguard for debugging, thus ensuring it won't break later. @Rick S, there's nothing you will find googling for it. I've searched many times, but there's absolutely no information.

Comment: Well... Consider yourself lucky for not debuggin an old Symbian (first Nokia "smart" phones). It was like this and worse for EVERY BUILD + bonus: crash the phone's kernel for 50% of the bugs. Same for Blackberry :)

Answer (score 5):

One quick method I found was to determine where the bottleneck of the build process was.  I realized it took an awfully long time to run ProGuard.  Then I realized that Proguard was running through the Android Support v4 library, which contains a huge amount of methods.

I included the lines of code below to reduce my build time from 3+ minutes to 45 seconds.

> -keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
>
> -keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }

However, the caveat is that you might be left with many unnecessary support library methods.  Therefore, I suggest using these lines during development, and then commenting it out for production build.

Comment: Sadly it makes absolutely no differences when building my projects, still 3+ minutes. Only the APK gets much bigger.

Answer (score 4):

Use proguard when you want to release your App. Do the test builds without Proguard.

Comment: We use proguard due to the stupid 64k method limit, Multidex is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in the file `app/build.gradle`  inside  `android {}`

```
android {
      ...
         android {
                   lintOptions { abortOnError false }
      }
      ...
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, we appreciate your input! Please edit your answer and explain a bit why this works.